# Export Modelsim waveforms as image for printing

Tags: vhdl, simulation, waveform, modelsim

I want to export the Modelsim waveforms of my simulated design in a form where they can look decent when printed. To be more specific, without the black background, in a vector format preferably.

Not something like this:
[image]

But instead like this:

[image]

The schematics are indicative, but I hope you get the point. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: iVerilog/GHDL + GTKwave and set the background to black and white. I always do this whenever printing a Testbench wave form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> in a form where they can look decent when printed

is a very subjective statement. Moreover, you can't really customize MSIM wave editor to display things very differently. Considered your question is quite broad, the simplest way I can think of is to **import your wave in a waveform viewer you like better**.

To export the waveform in a commonly usable vector format you can use the command line tool from vsim (2005 onward):

```
> wlf2vcd
> Usage: wlf2vcd [<Options>...] [-o <outfile>] <wlffile>
```

Which will convert your selected `*.wlf` file into a common *value change dump* file, holding all the informations you need.
(more on that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_change_dump)

The source waveform (`.wlf`) file is commonly generated by any modelsim simulation and saved, when you exit `vsim`, under `vsim.wlf` unless another name was specified.

Once you have your waveform in `.vcd` format, you can import it in any waveform viewer of choice and style its display according to your preference.

You can check for viewers in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveform_viewer , or you can even code your own, provided you understand VCD syntax.

---

#### Alternative

Unless you have to deal with plenty of waveforms, objects and processes, and instead make a functional waveform focused on a specific behaviour, *I would reccomend using a simple wave editor* to display what you need to.

My personal favourite when I have to export waveforms I analyzed to colleagues which wouldn't benefit from MSIM view, I go to http://wavedrom.com/ which is quick enough to make an effective (and -*IMHO*- pretty) graph.

Comment: Wavedrom is amazing. Very beautiful graphs. However, as both you and @Elbehery suggested in comments I will probably go with .vcd and GTKWave.

Answer (score 2):

You can undock the window 
[image]

then select the following:

[image]

you get a nice image you can insert into a doc and print
[image]